# yes/no field appears as textbox when designing form

Tags: ms-access

I have this odd issue when building a form in design view for an Access (2016) database. I have various fields with a data type of Yes/No. When creating a new form based on this table and dragging in fields from the Field List a text box appears instead of a checkbox. When I right click on the field the Check Box option in the 'Convert To Check Box' menu entry is greyed out.

I've tried adding a new checkbox and setting the control source to one of the Yes/No fields which does work but it's inconvenient to create and name all of these controls.

I've tried each of the form creation methods (Form, Form Design, Blank Form choosing the control source and Form Wizard) all with the same result. I've tried specifying the default value for the Yes/No fields (No) but that makes no difference.

Is this a bug, or just an awkward design? I'm pretty sure I've created other DBs where the boolean fields have automatically produced checkboxes in design mode. This DB is super simple - it has only one table which I created today so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Can you add an image and some code to your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newly created forms in Access (should) automatically copy the control and it's attributes as specified under *Lookup* in table design.

Go to table design for the table you want to adjust, and adjust it according to the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'd forgotten about the display control field, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem. For me, it was after moving from brave ol Access 2003 on Windows 7 to Access 2007 on Windows 10.

With 2003, dragging Yes/No fields from the field list onto the form displays checkboxes. It is very convenient when there are many Yes/No fields on a form, much faster than assigning a control source to a bunch of individual unbound checkboxes.

But with Access 2007, I confirm that dragging will drop a textbox ! Whereas dragging lookup fields works normally : it drops comboboxes.

This is a very odd bug !

The only (odd as well!) way I could make Access 2007 come back to normal was to drag at the same time a Combo AND a Checkbox ! Then the next Yes/No  fields would be dropped as Checkboxes. Very odd !

I find the 2007 FieldList absolutely horrible compared to 2003

Extremely slow, especially on linked tables.
Stupidly merged with the Property Sheet, so that you cannot have your Field List AND your Property Sheet displaying together.
The Form's Property sheet is also merged with the Query's Property sheet of its record source (there were 2 different property sheets in Access 2003). You can never be sure that edits to a record source will be properly saved !!!
And do not forget to close the Access 2007 Field List before closing your Form, otherwise re-opening another form will take hours on a black Field List !

All in all I am really not happy with Access 2007 / 2010 on Windows 10...

phil

Answer (score -1):

There is no bug, I'm pretty sure you're just misunderstanding something (and your question isn't very clear).

Can you back up a bit and [edit] your question to add a bit of an explanation of what you're trying to do and what the end result will be, also also add an image showing the problem?  My main question for you is *why do you need to create so many text boxes?*  They should only be created once, and then done.  Hide or Show them if needed.

Anyhow, TextBoxes can not be "changed to" Checkboxes because they hold different types of data.  You could on the other hand convert between Toggle Buttons, Option Buttons and Checkboxes, to a checkboxes.

If you want checkboxes then don't use the field list to add them fist as text boxes.  Instead, just add a checkbox and then assign the field to it.

[image: img]

Comment: I have the same issue as the original questions.  Access PRO 2016, forms.  I drag two yes/no fields from the table where the lookup value was check box to a form where the fields become text boxes.  Is there a property(ies) I can edit to change them to check boxes.  I think the demo adding a new check box answers a different question.  Thanks for the help.